# ini_set disabled functions

Tags: linux, security, php, web-hosting

I'm working in a hosting company and I'm pretty new. One of the company's policies is disabling ini_set php function for security reasons. There are lots of clients that have shared hosting asking us to enable this function. My task is to find out how can we enable this function without putting others at risk. We use Redhat Enterprise 5 and Cpanel.

I would be grateful if anyone has an answer to this.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that it's generally unnecessary.  As cPanel specific advice, fire up easyapache and recompile it with suPHP support.  From there, your customer can create php.ini files inside their `public_html` directories that will be applied as a local PHP config.  It's not quite as convenient as ini_set(), but it will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution - use separate instance of PHP for each user what need ini_set() with different UIDs.

Yes, it needs more memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can (currently) set different `php.ini` configuration for different PHP versions installed on the same machine (VPS):

PHP5.6 with `ini_set()` allowed on its `php.ini`, meanwhile PHP7.0 with `ini_set()` NOT allowed on its `php.ini`.